# I new an Integer instance but it gives me a Long instance

Tags: java

Recently, I met a pitfall of Java, the codes are here:

```
    Number value = new Integer(10);
    value = value instanceof Long ? new Long(-value.longValue()) : new Integer(-value.intValue());

    System.out.println(value instanceof Integer);
    System.out.println(value.getClass());
```

I think the output is:

true
class java.lang.Integer

but, I am wrong, the right output is just the opposite:

false
class java.lang.Long

I can NOT understand why. So I disassemble the class file using `javap -c`, the following two lines(instructions) is strange to me:

```
50: i2l           
51: invokestatic  #10                 // Method java/lang/Long.valueOf:(J)Ljava/lang/Long;
```

Why? I want the same instance with object `value`, why did it give me the different?

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: The resulting type of the conditional operator cannot be more than one, it's always one, which decided at the compile time.

Comment: If you cast both results to Number then it should work as expected.  The above *should* give a compile error, since Integer cannot be cast to Long, but javac does some weird things.

Comment: This is a great example of why you should not use the ternary operator; because you don't understand the ternary operator.  Just use an if statement because a) you understand it and b) it is understood by junior java developers (while the ternary is not)

Answer (score 2):

The ternary operator *?* is taking in two operands namely *new Long(-value.longValue())* and *new Integer(-value.intValue())*.

According to the Java language specification http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2, both operands will first be unboxed (Long->long) and (Integer->int), see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8, and then the following rules are applied:

If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.
Otherwise, if either operand is of type float, the other is converted to float.
Otherwise, if either operand is of type long, the other is converted to long.
Otherwise, both operands are converted to type int.

Since after the unboxing step one of your operands is type *long*, the other is converted to long. And that should explain your results.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler needs to format your conditional statement to return a single type and not more than one:

```
value = value instanceof Long ? new Long(-value.longValue()) : new Integer(-value.intValue());
```

The ternary operator needs to decide to cast one of the two possible return types so the return type is consistent.

I find it simplest to understand this in the same way you would write a method:

```
public Long getNumber(int n) {
    if (value instanceof Long) {
        return new Long(-value.longValue());
    } else {
        return new Integer(-value.intValue()); // Not consistent with return type
    }
}
```

You need to specify a consistent return type in this instance.  If you instead return them all as `Number` it should work out ok:

```
public Number getNumber(int n) {
    if (value instanceof Long) {
        return (Number) new Long(-value.longValue());
    } else {
        return (Number) new Integer(-value.intValue());
    }
}
```

and similarly:

```
value = value instanceof Long ? (Number) new Long(-value.longValue()) : (Number) new Integer(-value.intValue());
```

Gives you the desired output.

The rules for how the Java ternary operator decides these conversions are outlined [here
 in the Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2)

They are based on the logic of preservation of information:

```
If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.

Otherwise, if either operand is of type float, the other is converted to float.

Otherwise, if either operand is of type long, the other is converted to long.

Otherwise, both operands are converted to type int.
```

Just to give some context on the logic behind these rules so they do not seem so arbitrary.

`Double` takes precedent as it is the most specific, i.e. you can imagine how chopping a `double` into an `int` would lose information (`(int) 0.555 -> 0`) as opposed to converting `int` to `double` there is no lose of information (`(double) 1 -> 1.0` )

Then `Float`, as `float` has less precision than `double` but more than `long` or `int`.

`long` comes next as it is the more precise version `int`, and lastly they are treated as `int`s

So since `int` is the least specific it will often be cast to other `Number` formats.